# Excel function expand counts into rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am adding a lookup sheet onto a large dataset of inventory for work, there are multiple jobs mixed on the list and potentially multiple lines of a given item if it has revisions. It is possible for the same item number to appear in more than one job

Column A has control numbers, columns D++ have results table working with index/match( )

What I am trying to put in B & C are helper functions column B is simply a countif( ) of values in A:A what I need help with is expanding the counts into row references in column C  something like this:

```
| Row | A    | B | C |
|-----|------|---|---|
| 4   | 1234 | 2 | 1 |
| 5   | 2332 | 1 | 1 |
| 6   | 9912 | 2 | 2 |
| 7   | 3785 | 3 | 3 |
| 8   | 3090 | 2 | 3 |
| 9   |      |   | 4 |
| 10  |      |   | 4 |
| 11  |      |   | 4 |
| 12  |      |   | 5 |
| 13  |      |   | 5 |
```

[Screenshot of data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv4BD.jpg)

I can work with any kind of return value really, starting from 1 or actual row(4) or even reference a4 etc.
Any assistance would be a huge help thank you.  {C+S+E} Array Functions are acceptable if needed.

Comment: Wait, what did it do to my table? In the preview before posting that was properly formatted!  And now it is trash. Sorry guys I tried to edit and do not see how to fix that. I will work up an image to insert I guess....

Comment: If you need to show tables in a question I find this link helpful:   https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#  Then just add code formatting around the table.

Comment: `XLOOKUP` returns a reference to the cell not just the contents as `VLOOKUP` does.  So two XLOOKUP's together will return a range reference.  `=XLOOKUP(1234,$M$3:$M$7,$N$3:$N$7,,,1):XLOOKUP(1234,$M$3:$M$7,$N$3:$N$7,,,-1)` will return a range from the first 1234 in the range to the last - you can then SUM, COUNT or whatever you want with the returned range (Note the 1 & -1 at the end of each function - 1 looks first to last (default), -1 looks last to first).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thank you for the tips. I will read up on xlookup after work. The table formatting is exactly the way I did it. The attached screenshot is from the preview of this post before I hit submit.  So it should have been the same.

Comment: A couple of thoughts:  (a) you mentioned using CSE array formulas, and that made me think you may not have O365 that gives you access to dynamic arrays…  which then also means you wouldn’t have access to XLOOKUP yet.  (b) I looked at the link in your answer.  Your question doesn’t really explain the logic of column C other than to say “row references”…  I would not have known what you intended for column C until after I saw your answer link.  In the future I’d recommend being more clear about explaining the desired logic.

Comment: Valid points. A big Part of why I ended up here asking for help was I only had an unclear idea of what I wanted at the time.  As luck would have it I found my own solution by chance.  Feel free to suggest edits to align question and answer if you wish. I am open to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding what I was looking for.
[This Link](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-repeat-rows-a-specified-number-of-times/#3_Use_the_VLOOKUP_Function_to_Repeat_Rows_a_Specified_Number_of_Times_in_Excel) uses helper columns with `VLOOKUP( )` range lookups.

So in addition to your data add a column with the number of how many you want each to repeat.

A helper column starting from 1 that adds its previous with the repeat value

Then in the output area number the rows or just use the rows( ) to vlookup for the row number from the helper column that added app the repeat values and it will give you the correct row.